# how to run Selenium ChromeDriver with cookies from actual Chrome installation?

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies

I want to use Selenium(python) to log in to several sites and I need to get all my Chrome cookies,
How should I do this?

Comment: There are multiple questions like this

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question, anyways:

Do the following:

```py
# Remember to import
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
# Your user agent
options.add_argument("YOUR_USER_AGENT")

# Path to chrome application
options.add_argument("CHROME_APPLICATION_PATH")

# Path to chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="CHROME_DRIVER_PATH", options=options)
```

You will need to do some research about your own system and see what exactly is your user-agent (there are a million site that tell you)

As well as finding the correct path for your chrome application.

Then, proceed normally, this will execute chrome as if you opened it yourself.